# Array with different object types in mongodb's schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm developing my application using node.js and mongoose. I have an schema called `categories` and it contains a key named `content`, and i need to assign it different types of object, like bellow.

```
const categorySchema = new Schema({
  label: { type: String, required: true },
  content: [
         { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Videos" },
         { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Games" }
       ]
});
```

so the object type in typescript would be

```
content: Array<VideosType | GamesType>
```

any idea how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Schema.Types.Mixed`  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed :

```
const categorySchema = new Schema({
  label: { type: String, required: true },
  content: [{ type: Schema.Types.Mixed }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having multiple types then u can just **create an array of mixed type** which will essentially accept any type within the array.

```
content: Array
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

```js
const PriceFilterSchema = new Schema<PriceFilter>({
  filterType: { type: String, required: true /* PRICE_FILTER */ },
  tickSize: { type: String, required: true },
});
const LotSizeSchema = new Schema<LotSize>({
  filterType: { type: String, required: true /* LOT_SIZE */ },
  stepSize: { type: String, required: true },
});

//Main schema
const SymbolsSchema = new Schema<SymbolType>({
  filters: [
    {
      type: MongooseSchema.Types.Mixed,
      // Here I used enum
      enum: [PriceFilterSchema, LotSizeSchema],
    },
  ],
});
```

I do not know if type checking is happening, BUT, it closes my needs

1. Display the usage of the scheme
2. Typed use of the entity in the code